# Best resources about Prime End Theory

Tags: general-topology, continuum-theory

I'm trying to find the best source for understanding prime ends of planar continua, in particular, of planar continua that do not separate the plane.  What I want to know is how one can make use of chains of crosscuts (not necessary prime ends) to show that two embeddings of a chainable continuum $X$ are not equivalent embeddings.  Any source (other than Mayer) on this?  Any input?  Thanks.

Comment: chapter 2 of C. Pommerenke, Boundary Behavior of Conformal Maps

Comment: Thanks @WillJagy I’ll check it out

Comment: No, that's a very specialized result; there's almost certainly no treatment of it in book form.  Nadler has an earlier paper(s) on isotopy classes of some arc-like continua, mostly compactifications of rays with remainder an arc.